# Show that $(-1)^n \left(n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ diverges with given limitations

Tags: limits

My assignment is to show that $x_n := (-1)^n \left(n-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ diverges. The only things I can use are the $\epsilon$-definition of the limit, functions $exp$ and $ln$, the fact that alternating zero-sequences converge to zero, the rules of adding, mutliplying etc. for limits, but not much more. The proof has to be as simplistic as possible. I can not use L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: $|x_n| \ge (n-1)^n \ge n-1$. Can you show that $y_n = n-1$ diverges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\left(n-\frac1n\right)^n\ge (n-1)^n\ge n-1,$$
hence the sequence terms (for $n\ge2$) are alternatingly $\ge1$ and $\le -1$.

Comment: Yes, that works. But I cannot remember that we talked about this...